Question About Solving RTSP Stream Delay Issue in OpenCV 4.7.0
I am using OpenCV 4.7.0 on Windows 11. Currently, I am receiving an RTSP stream from an IP camera and processing it with OpenCV, but I am experiencing a delay of 1500ms. Despite trying several methods to resolve the issue, the delay still persists, and I am seeking help.
Current situation:

OS: Windows 11
OpenCV version: 4.7.0
Receiving RTSP stream from an IP camera and processing it with OpenCV
Experiencing a delay of 1500ms in the RTSP stream

Attempts made:

Used OpenCV’s cv2.VideoCapture to receive the RTSP stream
Checked the network connection with the camera
Tried to reduce the delay through OpenCV’s buffer settings

Current approach:
import cv2

rtsp_url = 'rtsp://192.168.0.44:554/1'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(rtsp_url)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open RTSP stream")
    exit()

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    if not ret:
        print("Failed to retrieve frame")
        break

    cv2.imshow('RTSP Stream', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Question:

Are there any additional settings or code modifications to reduce RTSP stream delay?

